# Parse to AWS conversion

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-cognito, amazon-mobile-hub

As I am sure many others are currently doing, I am converting an app from Parse to use Amazon Web Services Mobile Hub. My app is an iPhone app written in Objective-C. I am having difficulty understanding their documentation and creating similar functions.

Specifically, I am having difficulty creating users and the user sign in. In Parse there is a simple way to create a UserObject which remembers the username, password, as well as Facebook authentication. I am trying to make a sign in page where the user gives his/her name and password. As well as uploading photo objects that have a relationship with the user data.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a good AWS tutorial or help describe how to create this login? Parse announced its ending before my app was finished so there is no need to transfer data. I am assuming it will be easier in the long run to convert it completely to AWS Mobile rather than creating a DB. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I decided to use Firebase instead of AWS. It has a simpler login process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Cognito is the service for building a login. Unfortunately, last I checked, they require you to bring your own identity provider to perform logins. There is a third party project, actually an AWS employee's personal project, to provide such a provider. It is: [LambdAuth](https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth). I have asked AWS to formally review it and support it. Some people are using it with some success.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Blogged about this recently - have you looked at these resources? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/resources-for-migrating-parse-applications-to-aws/

There's even an article about hosting your own parse server, which could be useful if you don't want to change any of your code: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have been searching through these resources. However, setting up my own parse server seems difficult and unnecessary. I do not need to migrate any data, and am instead trying just to use AWS mobile hub. But I cannot seem to find anything for a simple username and password login like parse's PFUser class.

Comment: Have you seen the cognito guides? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html

Comment: Is hosting my own parse server a better and simpler solution than converting to AWS Mobile? My app is simple. It just needs to save Photos and User Data. I have been perusing their documents and I have been finding it difficult to create a simple login with a username and password.